# :first-child pseudo is not applying

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some styles to first-child of `<dl>`. I meant to say that should be applied to first `<dd>`. But it works if i remove `<dt></dt>` in the `<dl>`.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Test</dt>
    <dd>One</dd>
    <dd>Two</dd>
    <dd>Three</dd>
    <dd>Four</dd>
    <dd>Five</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS:**

```
dl dd:first-child{border:1px solid red}
```

Comment: you can also just use 'dl dd:nth-child(1){border:1px solid red}'

Comment: You can achieve what you want with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316886/jquery-recognizing-div-as-a-list-item/24316946#24316946

Answer (score 5):

Use `first-of-type` instead:

```
dl dd:first-of-type{border:1px solid red}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Aqc4q/)

---

### The reasoning...

[**`first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the **first sibling of
>   its type** in the list of children of its parent element.

-vs-

[**`first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents **any element that is the
>   first child element** of its parent.

In your case, `first-child` wont work, because the first `dd` is not the *first child* of `dl`

Comment: Ok. What about browser support?

Comment: @PavanKumar - yes, support is the same as for `first-child`, see the linked articles for compatibility

Comment: This property is supporting ie9 onwards only as per http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/

Comment: I have checked in ie7 & ie8 just now. The above link also they mentioned ie9 onwards...