# jQuery recognizing div as a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know you're not supposed to put divs inside an unordered list, but lets say we have the markup noted below. with jQuery I would like to target every 3rd list-item: li:nth-child(3n). Looks like jQuery counts the div inside as a list-item as well, even though we specify li:eq(3n). How can we detect every 3rd list-item regardless of what else is inside the parent element. what's the point of even writing li:eq(3n) when 'li' is ignored?

html:

```
<ul class="hello">
    <div class="someDiv">a</div>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <div class="divider">b</div>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul.hello li:nth-child(3n)").css('color','red');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N565K/1/)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, as you can't have markup like that anyway.

Comment: Although the markup was invalid, technically the result you got is correct. It is selecting a "list item", that is the "nth-child" (including *all* siblings). nth-of-type is what you wanted.

Comment: `<div>` in `<ul>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - actually it's not, it's a horrible answer as you shouldn't have to use `nth-of-type` at all, the only valid child of an UL is a LI, and there's no telling what the browser does with invalid markup like that. And it's not a matter of "supposed to", every HTML standard known to man says you simply can't have anything but a LI element inside a UL.

Comment: @adeneo: my "comment" purely explained *why* he got that result. I did qualify it with the HTML being invalid. If I had meant it as an answer it would have been an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type(3n)` like this :

```
$("ul.hello li:nth-of-type(3n)").css('color','red');
```

for example nth-of-type(3n+2) - 3 represents a cycle size, n is a counter, and 2 are when is beginning

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/N565K/2/**